# SerializeArray to Serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to pass the creationForm and fileUpload to the backend.

I tried with formData but I had problems sending the file. File size was 0.

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('creationForm'));
formData.append("fileUpload", file);
//and then send the file
```

But I'm trying with serialize but I'm getting error 500 and it doesn't reach the backend (i put a debug breakpoint).

All the data is right on the console.log

How do I convert serializeArray to normal serialize?

```
 var formData = $('#creationForm').serializeArray();
    console.log(file);
    formData.push({name: "fileUpload", value: file});
    console.log(formData);
     $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/upload/testCase',
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
```

Comment: You make it easier for people if you provide a [mcve]. You can use the [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) feature for that. See also the guide on how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In your creationForm include this:

```
// html
<form id='creationForm' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

In your ajax include this:

```
 // ajax 
    $("#creationForm").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData(this); 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/upload/testCase',
      contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
    }
    });
    )};
```

Also, in your creationForm you can include **one hidden type text**, in order to php recognize the current ajax request. For example:

```
// in your creationForm 
<input type='hidden' id='sendData' name='sendData' value='send'>
```

The above input in php is just the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendData'])) {
if($_POST['sendData'] == 'send') {
// so here php take the ajax request.
}
}
```

Comment: i had that and you are missing the append of the file that is not on the form. And I said it didnt work.

Comment: All you need is the code that i mentioned. Also check my edited answer, because you need this to include in your html form.

Comment: Don't append the file. Just create the object FormData like above.